# Use HasMany OR HasOne in the same Model on Sencha Ext JS?

Tags: extjs

I am looking for a way to give a model the capability to use both hasmany and hasone relations based o the records it gets.

As far as I know, hasmany expects an array of objects while hasone expects an object itself.

I am consuming data from a SAP's soap services, and the same service sometimes sends only one record (gotten as an object) or several records (gotten as an array of objects). Unfortunately I have no access to the code of those services.

This is my store:

```
Ext.define('FamilyModel', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
    config : {
        fields : [ {
            name: 'index',
            type : 'string',
            mapping: 'indice_familia'
        },
        {
            name : 'id',
            type : 'string',
            mapping: 'familia'
        },
        {
            name: 'description',
            type: 'string',
            mapping: 'desc_familia'
        }],
        hasMany: [{
            model: 'ProductModel',
            name: 'products',
            associationKey: 'Materiales'
        }]  
    }
});
```

So, is it posible to handle this two kind of relations on the same model? Thanks!

Comment: It's still a hasmany, it just returns a single record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HasOne is only a special case of HasMany. Anyway, HasOne implementation was buggy in pre-ExtJS 5 versions so I'd always use HasMany.